# Adding collaborators but none of them can push to a Private repo

Tags: git, github

I am a relative newcomer in the GitHub world. Today I had to create a new Git-Hub repository for my work group. The code we will be working on is private so we decided to create a new Private repo. I added myself and my colleges to the repo as collaborators but we are not able to push to the repo. And when we try to do so we get the next message:

git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

We have already verified that the remote roots are well created.

Thank you !!

We want to be able to push to the directory, so we were expecting to be able to do so as normally when doing so in public repos we do not have any problem.

Comment: What does everyone get for `ssh -T git@github.com`?